# What if we return string in int main ( )?

Tags: c, return-value

I have a doubt in the below code

```
int main ( )
{
    return "hello" ;
}
```

In the above code we have to return int, but we are returning string instead.The code will compile with one warning,i.e

> "return makes integer from pointer without a cast (enabled by default) "

Please explain what happens in the above case?

Comment: "The code will compile" – then your compiler is non-conformant. If you are using GCC or clang, consider using `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99` (or c89 or c11) to compile your code.

Comment: The compiler will return the pointer as an integer, i.e. the address of the string literal. It might be truncated (if the pointer is 64-bit and `int` is 32 bits).Depending on which operating system you run on it might even truncate more, since e.g. POSIX systems like Linux or OSX only uses the low 8 bits of the value.

Comment: And *listen to the compiler warnings*, they are often a sign of you doing something you *should not do*.

Answer (score 4):

If the implicit conversion from `char*` to `int` (via `char [6]` to `char*`) is allowed, the returned `int` will have a the value of the address of the first element in the string literal. If this overflows the `int`, you get *undefined behaviour*. If not, one could assume that is a non-zero value, which will be interpreted by the OS as a failure exit code<sup>*</sup>.

---

<sup>* Note the allowed range of return values from `main` may be limited to 8 bits, signed or unsigned, so there is scope for a second overflow here.</sup>

Comment: The return code might be still 0 if the `(uintptr_t) "hello" & 0xff == 0`.

Comment: @Kay Sorry, it is too early. I don't see that.

Answer (score 2):

> but we are returning string instead

`return`ing string essentially means returning the *base address* of the string, which is nothing but a pointer.

As per chapter 6.8.6.4, `C11` standard, 3rd paragraph,

> If a return statement with an expression is executed, the value of the expression is
>   returned to the caller as the value of the function call expression. If the expression has a
>   type different from the return type of the function in which it appears, the value is
>   converted as if by assignment to an object having the return type of the function.

That says, the base pointer of the string `"hello"` will be converted to an `int` and will be returned back to the OS. So, here the pointer-to-integer conversion takes place, producing the warning.

However, worthy to mention, this conversion is neither *safe* nor *reliable*. As mentioned by Mr. **@Lundin** in the comments, the result of the conversion is implementation-defined.

Note: Usually, a non-zero exit code indicates a failure in the program, so it's likely that OS will treat your program has failed.

Comment: Though note that 6.3.2.3 says: `"An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation."` So there's no guarantee that the conversion will result in something meaningful.

Comment: @Lundin absolutely sir. very useful info. Will add that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When `"hello"` is returned as an `int`, It will have the pointer address of `"hello"` as an integer. Being a non-zero integer, it will be assumed that the program has exited as a failure.

Answer (score 0):

You would return the memory address of the string data.